# Latest top 5 xml child nodes from the xml file ? using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net how can i get latest top 5 xml child nodes from the xml files.

```
      <Books>
        <book>
            <author>xx</author>
             <title>abc</title>
        </book>
        <book>
             <author>yy</author>
             <title>efg</title>
        </book>
      </Books>
```

From the above i want access latest inserted book from the Books
  please help me.

Comment: Hm, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

When the latest books are added to the bottom of the xml you can do something like this
(I used top 2 for testing instead of top 5)

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        string xmlString = "<Books><book><author>xx</author><title>abc</title></book><book><author>yy</author><title>efg</title></book>" +
                            "<book><author>xx2</author><title>abc2</title></book><book><author>yy2</author><title>efg2</title></book></Books>";
        //load xml from string or file
        xml.LoadXml(xmlString);  
        int count = xml.SelectNodes("/Books/book").Count - 2;
        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes(string.Format("/Books/book[position() > {0}]", count));

        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {
            //do something with node
            Response.Write(xn.InnerText);
        }
```

Comment: Hans Derks, thanks for response, if latest books are added to bottom then how can we track

Comment: Mr. Hans Derk i will check and intimate you.